# How can I get the response from the Request in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there any way that I can get the `response.body` from the Request function in scrapy?

I have this:

```
request = Request("http://www.example.com",  callback = self.mytest)

def mytest(self, response)
     return response.body
```

Now I want to get `response.body` in a Python variable, How can I get that?

I want something like

`myresponse = Request("http://www.example.com").get('response')`

Answer (score 5):

*Is there a way to get the Response from a Request you just created?*  No, only the callback function has access to the Response.  Once inside the callback you can access the Request via response.request, but not vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

try using the scrapy inline requests: https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests/