# How can I covert the requests code to scrapy?

Tags: python-requests, scrapy

```
def get_all_patent():
    patent_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        res = requests.get(url).text
        patent_list.append(res)
    return patent_list
```

Because scrapy can't get response from request,reference:[How can I get the response from the Request in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916612/how-can-i-get-the-response-from-the-request-in-scrapy)
I want to extend the variable `patent_list`，But I can't get response body.

Can I through the `Request meta` or do something in `Response`?

Comment: Maybe if patent_list is a global variable that  is easy to solve,but if is not ?

Comment: Adding all response bodies to a list can be done either in callbacks (using a spider attribute) or by using scrapy's coroutine support, but... Why do you need to append all of this to a list? That doesn't seem like a very scrapy way to do things.